# Can I disable the unicorn in Firefox?

Tags: firefox

In Firefox 29 or later, if you use the "Customize" feature to remove everything from the menu, [a unicorn is displayed](http://www.askvg.com/tip-revealing-hidden-secret-unicorn-easter-egg-in-mozilla-firefox/). While this is very amusing, the reason I removed all those items is that I actually would like a blank menu, and the unicorn detracts from the minimalist aesthetic. Is there a way that I can disable the unicorn?

Comment: The only way would be to modify the source code.

Comment: Just curious,  why do you care if a menu you don't use (and so will never see) is blank or not?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Well, I *assumed* that I would never see it, but after that unicorn appeared, I can't stop looking at it.

Comment: Seek therapy....

Comment: @Moab Oh, I'm afraid I'm [too far gone](http://stackexchange.com/users/6517130/elogent?tab=reputation) for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add the following into a [userChrome.css](http://kb.mozillazine.org/UserChrome.css) file:

```
#PanelUI-popup #PanelUI-contents:empty::before
{
    background-image: none !important;
}
```

Then restart Firefox.

Comment: Never said recompiling it was the only way.

Comment: @Tim S. True (although someone else did in a comment). Quick edit.

Comment: Personally I think it'd be a great exercise for someone who's never done it. It's not a trivial thing, and being able to do so adds a relatively rare skill to the average computer user.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can disable it. Firefox is an open source project, so fork the code, remove it, and recompile it for yourself. Perhaps other folks may feel the same way as you and be interested in getting rid of the magical, yet fleeting creature.

The source code can be downloaded from [this site](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Developer_guide/Source_Code/Downloading_Source_Archives) (there are multiple ways of doing so.)

Comment: Edited with a url where you can download it. Googling for "firefox source code" would have returned this result.

Comment: So you're saying that this is impossible to do through some sort of add-on? If I were to make this change, how would I go about getting it accepted into the project?

Comment: You could probably do it with an add-on, but honestly the only reason I would do so was to learn about creating add-ons.  If you want to change the source on the Mozilla Developer Network, I'm sure their site has information about how to go about contributing to the project.

Comment: The reason I'm asking is because, if you're going to go to the trouble to write this answer, you might as well include the relevant links and other information.